# Adding style in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question how will I make this code as one line.

```
document.getElementById("messageBodyView").style["background-color"] = "#ffffff";
document.getElementById("messageBodyView").style["border"] = "none";
```

I mean to make it shorter. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Wrap desired functionality in a function and call it? Not sure what else you could do here - the native DOM API doesn't lend itself to fluent calls if that's what you're going for

Comment: may be create css class with those styles and add the class with js…!

Comment: Relevant reference: [w3c Dynamic style - manipulating CSS with JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript)